# VML Rectangle vs Svg rectangle

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg, jquery-svg, vml

Please refer below SVG rectangle.

```
<rect id="container_svg_ChartArea" x="89.5" y="58" width="1240.5" height="448.5"
 fill="transparent" stroke-width="0.5" opacity="0.3" stroke="Gray"/>
```

VML rectangle.

```
<v:rect
   fillcolor="green"
   style="top:1;left:1;width:50;height:50">
   </v:rect>
```

Why can't I use x and y attribute in VML like SVG?

The above VML rect works in  IE7 and IE5 mode and not showing IE7 browser with IE7 document mode. Why?

I found below link.

[How do I get VML working in standards mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885381/how-do-i-get-vml-working-in-standards-mode)

If I set **position absolute** means it will show rectangle in all kind of browsers with different kind of document code?

What is the reason? If am having more number of rectangle and path means need to set position absolute for all elements?  How can I convert simple SVG code to VML code?

Comment: @downvoter: without comment i can't get what's wrong in my question ?

Comment: not a reason to downvote, but I can't help but wonder why do you still support IE5

Comment: no not for IE5 am using IE7, and IE8. i need VML rect works in IE7 browser with IE5 doc mode but not in IE7 doc mode.